# PHP Crawlers para sites externos API PHPcrawl

Tags: php, api, algoritmo-de-busca, web-crawler

Boa noite pessoa
Sou novo no assunto, estou tentando construir um motor de busca para sites externos (indexador) com PHP, achei uma API, que disponibiliza um Crawler, porém ele parece apenas pesquisar coisas dentro de apenas um site especifico, o nome da API é PHPCrawl, gostaria que alguém que tenha conhecimento nessa ferramenta, pudesse me dizer sé é possível buscar outros sites externos, e não apenas tags dentro de um só.
http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/about.html <- essa é a API
desde já agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas é basicamente isto que o crawler deve fazer, caberá você usar um banco de dados com a lista do sites que deseja escanear e um cron para agendar os escaneamentos, a cada **cron** preferivelmente para agendar os escaneamentos, neste script você passaria o argumento do site que deseja escanear, por exemplo: `$crawler->setURL($argv[1])`.

Não espere que uma unica requisição php deverá processar inúmeros sites, isso será pessimo para o seu servidor, o Google, Yahoo, Bing escaneiam periodicamente sites diferentes e por rotinas e provavelmente eles tem limite de escaneamento de um site por hora e continuam apenas depois.

Se apenas um requisição e um script php tentasse acessar várias urls, a aplicação ficaria em um longo processo que poderia levar horas e dependendo não o [*Garbage collection (GC)*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coletor_de_lixo_(inform%C3%A1tica)) do PHP não iria conseguir limpar o uso o que faria o consumo do processador ou memória ir aumentando até o seu servidor começar a travar.

A maneira mais apropriada correta (não necessariamente a correta) é escanear um site de cada vez e colocar um limite e tentar continuar de onde parou se for usar o limite. Lembre-se existem sites que podem ter mais de 50.000 páginas.

Comment: olha muito obrigado mesmo, me clareou bastante a ideia do que devo fazer, obrigado